# Splitting form into two pages causes error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have setup the laravel resource controller and utilized the edit and update methods to edit user profiles.  My profile form turned out to be too long, so I would like to split it into two forms.

The trouble is that the update function appears to be built into the resource controller - I tried just copy the method, add in my inputs and rename it.  I updated the routes and view, but received an error.   I also tried to have both forms call the same function, but the information that wasn't included in the form was delete from my db.

My question is, how do I split my form into two, so I can update my user profile from two forms instead of one?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you

For reference, here is my ContractorController

```
public function edit($id)
{
    //
    // get the contractor
    $contractor = Contractor::find($id);

    // show the edit form and pass the contractor
    return View::make('contractors.edit')
        ->with('contractor', $contractor);
}

public function update($id)
{
    //
    // validate
    // read more on validation at http://laravel.com/docs/validation
    $rules = array(
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    // process the login
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('contractors/' . $id . '/edit')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    } else {
        // store
        $contractor = Contractor::find($id);
        $contractor->name       = Input::get('name');
        $contractor->tag_line       = Input::get('tag_line');
        $contractor->contact_name      = Input::get('contact_name');
                    //would like to split items below into a separate form:
        $contractor->public_email       = Input::get('public_email');
        $contractor->phone       = Input::get('phone');
        $contractor->address_1      = Input::get('address_1');
        $contractor->city      = Input::get('city');
        $contractor->state       = Input::get('state');
        $contractor->zip      = Input::get('zip');
        $contractor->website      = Input::get('website');
        $contractor->story    = Input::get('story');

        $contractor->save();

        // redirect
        Session::flash('message', 'Successfully updated profile!');
        return Redirect::to('contractors');
    }
}
```

Start of form in edit.blade.php

```
{{ Form::model($contractor, array('route' => array('contractors.update', $contractor->id), 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'method' => 'PUT')) }}
```

Comment: I recommend you drop the resource controller and start with a restful one. Since you are gonna need more actions, views and routes to deal with. I believe you can transfer the input from step 1 to step 2 using `->withInput(Input::all())` in the redirect. But I can't be sure.

Comment: do it in client side with multi step form.

Comment: @user2094178  Can I use both restful and resource in the same controller as long as the routes are setup right?    I ask, because this same controller already has create and delete methods built in too.

Comment: Yes, you can even mix it like `Route::controller('users','UsersController'); Route::resource('users','UsersController');`

Comment: @user2094178 Great.  That was what I was hoping to hear.  Thank you